# Tomcat 5.5 Axis2 application scope problem - Unable to create single instance

Tags: web-services, scope, apache-axis, tomcat5.5

I have deployed an axis2 web service on Tomcat 5.5.  The web service functions as expected.  But I noticed I was getting duplicated log entries.  After researching it became clear that multiple instances of the class were being created - ie the first time it ran, one log entry; second time, two entries and so on.

I added the scope="application" parameter, but that has not solved the problem.  I added it both in the service tag and as a separate parameter tag to no avail.

This class has many key global variables, logging being one of them.  Frustrated as I am, I still haven't gotten to the point of deconstructing the globals (major overhaul, breaks code conventions in my department). Are global variables the culprit?  Or is there some other Tomcat/Axis2 config I am missing?

Will post services.xml or other code upon request.

Thanks in advance - Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem...don't necessarily understand why but I now have the correct behavior...

The services.xml file I created as part of the web service (WEB-INF/services/myService/META-INF) was being overridden by config in tomcat/conf/server.xml, where I had previously only referred to myService with a context block.  In order for myService to have unique service-level parameters, it has to have it's own   config in tomcat/conf/server.xml...not just a context reference.

It seems to me that this is not the best config...services and contexts in server.xml.  It's not dynamic that way.  Unfortunately I am following a standard set here many moons ago, so nothing I can do.